# Unable to connect to Litecoin Testnet with Litecoin Core on Mac

Tags: litecoin, mac

I've downloaded the LiteCoin Core for the Mac (High Sierra 10.13.3) in order to use the testnet for testing an online shopping cart. I'm not looking to mine any coins, just use the wallet. The application loads up correctly when connecting to the normal wallet, but when I add `testnet=1` to the litecoin.conf, it won't connect to the peers. When I look at the debug log, I see

```
2018-03-01 14:37:02 connect() to 104.236.211.206:19335 failed after select(): Connection refused (61)
2018-03-01 14:37:03 connect() to 173.209.44.34:19335 failed after select(): Connection refused (61)
2018-03-01 14:37:03 connect() to 173.209.44.34:19335 failed after select(): Connection refused (61)
2018-03-01 14:37:04 connect() to 66.178.182.35:19335 failed after select(): Connection refused (61)
2018-03-01 14:37:04 connect() to 66.178.182.35:19335 failed after select(): Connection refused (61)
2018-03-01 14:37:05 connect() to 173.209.44.34:19335 failed after select(): Connection refused (61)
```

I've tried adding an RPC user/pass, but still no go. Error 61 seems to relate to the service not running on the port on the destination machine. I'm in an office environment, so cannot make any network changes. Is there anything I'm missing?

Here is my current litecoin.conf

```
rpcuser=litecoinrpc
rpcpassword=mypasswordhere
testnet=1
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is you are using an older version of litecoind which is trying to get testnet3 instead of testnet4.

If this is the case, updating to the latest version should solve it.

See Reset Testnet section at https://blog.litecoin.org/litecoin-core-v0-14-2-release-ab6d2217405f

Comment: It was the newest version, 0.14.2. I even deleted it and reinstalled it